# Cakephp difference between read(null, $id) and read ($id)

Tags: cakephp

As the question states, I can't seem to find out information on the difference between both read statements when using it in a model

e.g. Model->read(null, $id) vs Model->read($id)

Can anyone share some light?

Thanks

Comment: How about just looking that up in the API? api.cakephp.org It is definitely there.

Comment: Well one of them won't be in the docs because it's invalid - where have you seen `->read($id)`? What is confusing about [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read)? Or [the source code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1579) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
read($fields, $id);
```

$fields is used to pass a single field name, as a string, or an array of field names; if left empty, all fields will be fetched.